# Magento - How to change Encryption Key

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Can anyone please direct me on how to change the Magento Encryption Key? I know it is located in `/app/etc/local.xml` but how to i change it to a different encryption key.

Comment: If you have existing users then you can't change the key unless you want them all to have to change their password.

Answer (score 1):

The encryption key is not used when saving passwords, but several modules use it to encrypt/decrypt data (PayPal for example). On a default install this is not used widely, so maybe you're good.

I would try changing the key in local.xml on a test server and explore what has happened.

Also, why do you need to change it exactly?